# Background mode is not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, background, xcode6

In my application I am getting update from server in every min.For background I am using the code

```
 UIApplication*  app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 bti = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    NSLog(@"Debug - Ending background task %d",bti);
    [app endBackgroundTask:bti];
    NSLog(@"Debug -  Background task %d ended",bti);
    bti = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}];
NSLog(@"Debug - Starting background task %d",bti);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target: self
                               selector: @selector(anyTask) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

But application is terminated after some time and getting log

```
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x15ddbf50> identifier: Background Content Fetching (79) process: DemoApp[628] permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundContentFetching owner pid:33 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownUI  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

I also used background fetch like this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
     (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
NSLog(@"Background fetch started...");
  [self repeatTask];
//    //---do background fetch here---


NSLog(@"Background fetch completed...");
```

}

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run in the background indefinitely using this technique. You can either use background fetch mode to allow your app to poll your server (but the frequency will be minutes or hours) or you can get your server to use push notifications to alert your app that there is new content. Your current approach is not very battery-friendly

If you are going to use background fetch mode then you need to invoke the supplied `completionHandler`  with the appropriate result -

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

or

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
```

or

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
```

at the end of `performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`

For example

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
     (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
         NSLog(@"Background fetch started...");
         if ([self repeatTask]) { // //---do background fetch here--- returns YES if new data
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
         }
         else {
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
         }
         NSLog(@"Background fetch completed...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have also used background fetch here, but same thing happens in that case.

Comment: Can you show your code `fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:`

Comment: But how to fetch data in a loop here?

Comment: You don't need to - The operating system will periodically invoke `performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`, but as I said it won't be every minute.  The period will be much longer.  iOS uses the time your method takes to execute and the completion value (i.e. new data or not) to determine an appropriate interval to call your method

Comment: I need to run this task every minute :(

Comment: Then you need to pick another platform. iOS doesn't work that way.  Polling is very inefficient in terms of network traffic and battery life.  You should adopt push notifications

Comment: But there are lot of application in which background mode works, like gaana.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62586/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user123456).